# Driving to DC from Basye

Tags: trains, public-transport

We are staying at a resort in Basye this summer and want to know the easiest way to take a couple of day trips into DC.  I'm thinking that we would drive most of the way in, then use a park and ride and take the metro to the National Mall.

I'm assuming that traffic and parking in DC would be difficult.

Comment: by public transport I suppose? Or only train or bus? Or car? Please specify in your question text, the tags can be ambiguous!

Comment: And I forgot to ask, what do you mean by best? Cheapest, fastest, most fancy, ...? Please edit your question to specify. Until you make these precisions, I am voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Traffic and parking depend on the timing of your trip. I would probably just drive all the way in, based on my experiences visiting the western suburbs frequently between 2006 and 2011, and visiting DC nearly weekly from Lexington VA in 1995-1996.

Answer (score 2):

As a Washingtonian, I don't think the traffic would be the problem, but parking might, not only in the city, but at those Metro stations that offer commuter parking. As you'll be about 125 miles from the city, you might consider driving to Tyson Corner, a massive shopping area with huge parking lots, and taking the Silver Line Metro from there (1943 Chain Bridge Road).

A quick Google for route says it's 107 miles, approximately 1 hour 45 minutes, by taking Interstate 81 North to Interstate 66 East to Virginia 123 South, Chain Bridge Road/Dolley Madison Boulevard.